# Why is this infinite loop happening in the following code? React & useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm going to give you 2 versions of a component i wrote. Why does the FIRST one give me an infinite loop, while the second one works fine?

I isolated the problem but i am wondering why the logic doesn't follow 'under the hood'. No doubt some black magic from `useState`

```
//THROWS INFINTE LOOP ERROR
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Popover, PopoverHeader, PopoverBody } from 'reactstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faInfoCircle } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

const HelpIcon = (props) => {
  HelpIcon.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.bool]),
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  };

  const [isOpen, toggleIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span
        className="pointer text-body"
        id={props.id}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />
      </span>
      <Popover
        trigger="legacy"
        placement="left"
        isOpen={isOpen}
        target={props.id}
        toggle={toggleIsOpen(!isOpen)}{//<-----look here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
      >
        {props.title !== false && (
          <PopoverHeader className="text-body bg-light">
            {props.title}
          </PopoverHeader>
        )}

        <PopoverBody className="text-xs cart__rebate_description text-body bg-white">
          {props.children}
        </PopoverBody>
      </Popover>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default HelpIcon;
```

...AND...

```
//THIS ONE WORKS
//NOTICE THE EXTRA FUNCTION THAT CALLS USESTATE, INSTEAD OF CALLING IT DIRECTLY
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Popover, PopoverHeader, PopoverBody } from 'reactstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faInfoCircle } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

const HelpIcon = (props) => {
  HelpIcon.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.bool]),
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  };

  const [isOpen, toggleIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => toggleIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span
        className="pointer text-body"
        id={props.id}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />
      </span>
      <Popover
        trigger="legacy"
        placement="left"
        isOpen={isOpen}
        target={props.id}
        toggle={toggle}
      >
        {props.title !== false && (
          <PopoverHeader className="text-body bg-light">
            {props.title}
          </PopoverHeader>
        )}

        <PopoverBody className="text-xs cart__rebate_description text-body bg-white">
          {props.children}
        </PopoverBody>
      </Popover>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default HelpIcon;
```

Comment: Change this `toggle={toggleIsOpen(!isOpen)}` to this `toggle={() => toggleIsOpen(!isOpen)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is wrong, and it causes you the loop:

```
toggle={toggleIsOpen(!isOpen)} // you call the function in a loop
```

It should be:

```
toggle={() => toggleIsOpen(!isOpen)}
```

If you really want to use it your way you must do a double arrow function like this:

```
const toggle = isOpen => () => {
    toggleIsOpen(isOpen)
}

// and use it like

toggle={toggle(!isOpen)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are instantly calling `toggleIsOpen` in the first example. You should always wrap it with another function if you want to call it with arguments other than `toggle` prop provides.

Answer (score 0):

it is causing infinite since changing state cause re-render in react; if your function call don't cause re-render it will work( kinda, not causing infinite loop) something like this

```
foo = () => console.log(9)

toggle={foo()}
```

but since set state will cause re-render your app stuck; here is the call-stack (kinda)

1. `render` is called;
2. it will reach the `set-state`
3. `state` changes
4. calling `render` again
5. it will reach the `set-state`
6. `state` changes
7. calling `render` again

and ....